# Elements selection by class with mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to select all elements with classes `*_maxim` in my code and append new classes `*_david`. For example, if one of the initial classes was `header_maxim`, I need to get `header_david` as a new class name.

Comment: Do consider separating `header` from `maxim`, to get two classes which are easier to work with.

Comment: Rajaprabhu, I’ve looked through Javascript references, and I’ve found out than I can select elements or even number of elements to manipulate them, but all these things — by particular ID or class or element name, not by some mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('*[class$=_maxim]').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass(this.className.replace(/^(.*)_maxim$/, '$1_david'));
});
```

---

- `$('*[class$=_maxim]')` - select all elements whose `class` attribute value ends with `_maxim` (look up [Attribute Ends With Selector `[name$="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)).
- `.each()` - for each such element (look up [`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/))
- `addClass()` - add a class to the element (look up [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/))
- `this.className.replace(/^(.*)_maxim$/, '$1_david')` - the new class name to add will be the old class name from which `_maxim` is replaced with `_david` (`this` within the `each` callback refers to the element currently being matched; look up [`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) and [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)).

Comment: Since you know the class definitely ends with `_maxim`, you could use substring instead of regex

Comment: Thanks! That not just helped me, but also made things easier and much more clear.